# Cannot connect to Azure SQL database from Azure Container Instance in different subnets

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-container-instances

I have an Azure Container Instance (ACI) and an Azure SQL database.
I'm having problems when I try to connect the ACI to the SQL

Infrastructure looks like this:
One vnet with two subnets.
The ACI has a private IP in subnet1.
The SQL has a private endpoint in subnet2.
Subnet1 has Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups configured under subnet delegation.
No NSG between the subnets.
Routing tables connected to the subnets routes traffic within the vnet.

The log in the ACI complains about not beeing able to connect to the database on port 1433.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that the problem was DNS.
ACI doesn't use the DNS servers configured on the vnet so you have to configure DNS for the ACI:
[How to get Azure Container Instances using my DNS server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64700687/how-to-get-azure-container-instances-using-my-dns-server)